# How can I create SQL Server database from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

This question can be a stupid one, but I cannot find any option to create DB right in visual studio.
I don't have any SQL client installed currently and I don't want to install any just in sake of create DB option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you can see the server explorer (View -> Server Explorer or Ctrl +W, L)
Right click data connections
click "Create new Sql Server database..."